# Referencing Namespaces in Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have simple code

```
@using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

@helper ADFullName() 
{
   using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
   {
      var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);

   }
}
```

Of course, the `UserPrincipal` and  `PrincipalContext` namespaces cannot be found because `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` does not exist in the namespace system.

Can you only user certain namespaces in .cshtml pages?

I also tried adding the assemblies in the Web.Config file and that did not work either.

Comment: change `@using` to `@model`. Like this: `@model System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` without semicolon at the end. This will work if you have  a model to show in your view. In case you need to reference others models, try to include all Namespaces inside razor context by removing `helper ADFullName()`. And keep this:  `@{ }`

Comment: I do not have a model to show in my view

Comment: Then use `@{  }` and automatically you will access NameSpaces.

Comment: Didn't work either, this seems pretty straight forward I don't know why it doesn't work. I'm going to try using a model and see if that will work, it's just the syntax in MVC seems to think that a lot of methods don't exist for some reason